# a4j:jsfunction did not get triggered

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I expect to see the alert, unfortunately the js-function-body of setTempIshCaseId() never got triggered as Firebug-JS-Debugger is telling me.

My jsf-Code (surrounded by a form-Tag):

```
<t:div id="setTempIshCaseIdContainer">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="setTempIshCaseId" reRender="debugIshCaseId" > 
    <a4j:actionparam name="tempIshCaseId" assignTo="#{CaseController.tempIshCaseId}"/> 
    </a4j:jsFunction>
    <h:outputText id="debugIshCaseId" value="#{CaseController.tempIshCaseId}" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR:red;"/>
</t:div> 
<a4j:commandLink id="preSaveCaseButton" onclick="setTempIshCaseId();" title="#{resources.labels['biobank_lims_saveTable']}" reRender="jsonpRemoteURLs,hNumberRemoteURL,eNumberRemoteURL,ishCaseRemoteURL,tempIshCaseIdContainer" oncomplete="jQuery('a#form_saveCaseButton').click()">
</a4j:commandLink>
```

my javascript-code:

```
function setTempIshCaseId(){
    alert('BP');
    console.log("setTempIshCaseId() Start ");
    // setze den Wert des a4j-js-function action param
    var ishCaseId = jQuery('#form_ish').val(); 
    jQuery('#form_tempIshCaseId').text(ishCaseId);
    jQuery('#form_debugIshCaseId').text(ishCaseId);
    console.log("setTempIshCaseId() Ende ");
}
```

Why did setTempIshCaseId() doesn't get called after clicking preSaveCaseButton? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Problem solved. After reading this tutorial: 
http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/06/using-richfaces-a4jjsfunction-sending-an-ajax-request-from-any-javascript/

It is obvious that I have to pass parameters for actionParam-attribute to the JavaScript-function like this:

```
onclick="setTempIshCaseId(jQuery('#form_ish').val());"
```